# Failed umount /home (ZFS) on shutdown

Tags: syslog, zfs, unmounting

During shutdown I notice an error reported in the logging messages on the screen that the `umount`ing of `/home` (a ZFS filesystem) failed. (After restart I don't find any respective log entry in the logfiles, though, so I have no precise information about that.) I am running Xubuntu 12 with Linux 3.2.0.

My questions:

1. Where is the appropriate place to look for the appropriate log files? (There's no respective infos in syslog, and dmesg contains only months old entries.)
2. Is there some ZFS specific configuration for the umount necessary that my system may be missing?
3. Or can I (safely) just ignore that message? (A couple reboots did not show any problem with `/home` on that file system.)
4. Any other related hints are also welcome.

Comment: Are you using fuse-zfs or zfs-on-linux (ZoL)?

Comment: @myaut; Sorry, I cannot tell. The man page of the zfs command mentions ZoL in one place (speaking about a future feature). - If it's important, how could I check or verify that?

Comment: If `/proc/spl/` directory exists, it is definitely a ZoL. It is just a clarification, but since ZoL and fuse-zfs will behave differently on shutdown, it may be important.

Comment: @myaur; Yes, `/proc/spl` exists (and beneath there's a `/proc/spl/kstat/zfs/` directory).